# Android Firebase: I am trying to get all the values of "Images" in the following database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following code:

```
db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("Images", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Images").getChildren()));
                }
```

More importantly how do I seperate the data considering all "Images" have different number of values in them.The dataSnaphot is returning the data but I cannot parse through it.
[image]

Comment: I want all the values of "Images"...it has image links the ones I have circled.
and I want to seperate the data according to from where they came from.
strings from 0 1 2 sepetrately and 0 1 seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all those childrens (`-L41Yyy...`, `-L41bHhc...`) are direct childs of your Firebase root, to get all those links, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.child("images").getChildren()) {
                String key = dSnapshot.getKey();
                String link = dSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", key + ": " + link);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The outout will be something like this:

```
0: https://
1: https://
2: https://
0: https://
1: https://
```

As you can see, it also displays the number before the link as you requested.

Comment: One small request...the third chlid has no "Images" so how do I show it as `null`

Comment: You're welcome @PembaTamang ! You can create an if statement. `if(!dSnapshot.exists()) {}`. Which means if `dSnapshot` does not exists at a particular location, do what you want to do.

Comment: the if statement is not executing. I was setting the key and link as "null"
`if(!dSnapshot.exists()){ key = "null"; link = "null";}else{.....your working code...}`<br/> but they don't show up in the output. I think the `DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.child("Images").getChildren()` is only taking the keys that have Images ignoring the 3rd one.

Comment: If you are using `"null"` as a String is totally different than using `null` as value. In this case use `equal()` method like this: your child `equals("null")`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo